# Get specific key value pair from multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["submission_id"] => int(28)
    ["date"] => string(22) "2010-10-18 15:55:33+02"
    ["user_id"] => int(12)
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["submission_id"] => int(37)
    ["date"] => string(22) "2010-11-21 16:02:07+01"
    ["user_id"] => int(23)
  }
```

I want to get only the user_id key values from this array. I could obviously loop over it, but I was wondering if there was a quicker way.

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (might not be quicker though, as it will make a function call per array element):

```
function getUserId($a) {
    return $a['user_id'];
}

$user_ids = array_map('getUserId', $array);
```

Apart from that, looping is the only way (`array_map` makes loop anyway).

Comment: Thx! My proposal (PHP > 5.3): `$user_ids = array_map(function ($row) {
 return $row['user_id'];
}, $array);`

Answer (score -3):

You can access only the user_id values like this if you know the array index you want to access:

```
$arr = your array here..
echo $arr[0]['user_id'];
echo $arr[1]['user_id'];
```

Comment: This method would not scale as not able to know the total elements