# Getting a particular element from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in my PHP code which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [subject_id] => 1
        [subject] => Math
        [default_selection] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [subject_id] => 2
        [subject] => Physics
        [default_selection] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [subject_id] => 3
        [subject] => Chemistry
        [default_selection] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [subject_id] => 4
        [subject] => Biology
        [default_selection] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [subject_id] => 5
        [subject] => Statistics
        [default_selection] => 0
    )

)
```

I would like to get the value of [subject] where [subject_id]= 2. Is there any direct/shortcut to do this in PHP or I need to run a foreach loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this just once on the same data, simply run a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
    $foundArray = null;

    foreach ($array as $subArray) {
        if ($subArray['subject_id'] == 2) {
            $foundArray = $subArray;
            break;
        }
    }

    var_dump($foundArray);
?>
```

If you need to check `subject_id`'s a lot with the same data (in the same request), you can associate your key with the `subject_id` and refer to it that way:

```
<?php
    $assoc = array();

    foreach ($array as $subArray) {
        $assoc[$subArray['subject_id']] = $subArray;
    }

    var_dump($assoc[2]);
    var_dump($assoc[3]);
    var_dump($assoc[4]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map)

Use this function:

```
function getSubject($subject) {
   if  ($subject['subject_id'] == 2) return $subject; 
}
```

Usage:

```
$subjects = array_map('getSubject', $array);
var_dump($subjects);
```

Reference: [Get specific key value pair from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554981/get-specific-key-value-pair-from-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

New in PHP 5.5 is the [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, which will probably acheive what you're asking for (ie searching without using `foreach()`):

```
$searchForSubjectID = 2;
$index = array_search($searchForSubjectID, array_column($data, 'subject_id'));
$subject = $data[$index]['subject'];

print $subject;  //prints 'Physics'
```

If you're not on PHP 5.5 yet, there is [a compatibility library for this function](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to select the correct element:

```
<?php
    function getSecondSubject( $element ){
        return $element["subject_id"] == 2;
    }

    $only_subject_two = array_filter( $all_subjects, "getSecondSubject" );

    $subject = $only_subject_two["subject"];
?>
```

You can use some trickiness (like a variable) to make the `subject_id` you're looking for variable, if you need that.